# JavaScript: How can I remove any words containing (or directly preceding) capital letters, numbers, or commas, from a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to write the code so it removes the "bad" words from the string (the text).

The word is "bad" if it has comma or any special sign thereafter. The word is not "bad" if it contains only `a to z` (small letters).

So, the result I'm trying to achieve is:

```
<script>
String.prototype.azwords = function() {
   return this.replace(/[^a-z]+/g, "0");
}

var res = "good Remove remove1 remove, ### rem0ve? RemoVE gooood remove.".azwords();//should be "good gooood"
//Remove has a capital letter
//remove1 has 1
//remove, has comma
//###  has three #
//rem0ve? has 0 and ?
//RemoVE has R and V and E
//remove. has .
alert(res);//should alert "good gooood"
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return this.replace(/(^|\s+)[a-z]*[^a-z\s]\S*(?!\S)/g, "");
```

It tries to match a word (that is surrounded by whitespaces / string ends) and contains any (non-whitespace) character but at least one that is not `a-z`. However, this is quite complicated and unmaintainable. Maybe you should try a more functional approach:

```
return this.split(/\s+/).filter(function(word) {
    return word && !/[^a-z]/.test(word);
}).join(" ");
```

Comment: Thank you. But what about this:
return this.replace(/(^|\s+)[a-z]*[^a-z\s]\S*(?!\S)/g, "");
so you don't need to .trim(), once you replace with "" instead of " "?

Comment: @Haradzieniec: You're right! I thought that would leave no space between the words.

Comment: Follow-up on the JSPerf I mentioned in comments to my solution: I ran the benchmarking tests in a few browsers to see which solution was objectively faster. Chrome: my solution is faster; Firefox, this one is. IE, however, threw an error when I tried to use this solution. I'm not sure why. Depends on how important IE-compatibility is to you but might be worth looking into. [Results here.](http://jsperf.com/plain-old-js-vs-jquery-and-regex-filter)

Comment: @guypursey: outdated Internet Explorers do not support [Array `filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), but you can easily shim it for them

Comment: @Bergi Strange that JQuery doesn't include a shim for this! Perhaps JQuery offers another method for achieving the same thing as `filter` but across browsers? It seems a shame to have to build a shim for IE when the whole point of JQuery is to take care of such things. Not that I'm complaining to you, just mentioning it in case there's another way :-)

Comment: jQuery never was meant to handle data. All it can do is DOM, Ajax and Animation (it has namespaced map, grep, inArray etc, but those are poor copies). To get cross-browser compability, use [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) and/or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

okay, first off you probably want to use the word boundary escape `\b` in your regex. Also, it's a bit tricky if you match the bad words, because a bad word might contain lower case chars, so your current regex will exclude anything which does have lowecase letters.

I'd be tempted to pick out the good words and put them in a new string. It's a much easier regex.

```
/\b[a-z]+\b/g
```

NB: I'm not totally sure that it'll work for the first and last words in the string so you might need to account for that as well. http://www.regextester.com/ is exceptionally useful.

EDIT: as you want punctiation after the word to be 'bad', this will actually do what I was suggesting

```
(^|\s)[a-z]+(\s|$)
```

Comment: How are you going to use that? `.match(…).join(" ")`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
 var res = "good Remove remove1 remove, ### rem0ve? RemoVE gooood remove.";     
 var new_one = res.replace(/\s*\w*[#A-Z0-9,.?\\xA1-\\xFF]\w*/g,'');


//Output `good gooood`
```

*Description*:

```
             \s*           # zero-or-more spaces
             \w*           # zero-or-more alphanumeric characters 
             [#A-Z0-9,.?\\xA1-\\xFF]  # matches any list of characters
             \w*           # zero-or-more alphanumeric characters

             /g  - global (run over all string)
```

Comment: It does not remove `remöve` - not sure whether that is a problem

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for this notie. I was trying to note that either. Yes, that is a problem. As far as I understand, [#A-Z0-9,.?] should be replaced with some kind of [^a-z], but I have no luck with that. So the list of allowed symbols is more preferable than a long list of symbols to be excluded.

Comment: @Bergi sorry, didnt notice, i fixed my response: added `\xA1-\xF6`

Comment: @Haradzieniec i fixed my response, suppose it should work (added ASCII range as well)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I wouldn't recommend changing the prototype of String (or of any native object) if you can avoid because you leave yourself open to conflicts with other code that might define the same property in different ways. Much better to put custom methods like this on a namespaced object, though I'm sure some will disagree.

Second, is there any need to use RegEx completely? (Genuine question; not trying to be facetious.)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/guypursey/BxGND/2/) is an example of the function with plain old JS using a little bit of RegEx here and there. Easier to comment, debug, and reuse.

Here is the code:

```
var azwords = function(str) {
   var arr = str.split(/\s+/),
       len = arr.length,
       i = 0,
       res = "";
   for (i; i < len; i += 1) {
       if (!(arr[i].match(/[^a-z]/))) {
           res += (!res) ? arr[i] : " " + arr[i];
       }
   }
   return res;
}

var res = "good Remove remove1 remove, ### rem0ve? RemoVE gooood remove."; //should be "good gooood"

//Remove has a capital letter
//remove1 has 1
//remove, has comma
//###  has three #
//rem0ve? has 0 and ?
//RemoVE has R and V and E
//remove. has .

alert(azwords(res));//should alert "good gooood";
```

Comment: This returns `"good gooood "` (notice the trailing blank). See my answer for a more concise implementation of that word filter :-)

Comment: You are probably right but your code is longer and I'm not sure if it works faster. Anyway, thanks for the solution. It looks clear. What about the blank space after the right word, please use .trim() :)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for pointing me to your own solution. I like the concise chained functional approach; it's very neat and uses the `filter` method which in my sticking to plain old JS I didn't think of :-) I've corrected the trailing blank by modifying my code.

Comment: @Haradzieniec I've fixed the trailing blank, not with `trim` but by correcting the concatenation up front. I used JSPerf to see which is faster and in my browser, it looks as though mine might be. You can see the results [here](http://jsperf.com/plain-old-js-vs-jquery-and-regex-filter). I declared called JQuery in my code even though I don't use any JQuery in my solution because you said you were using it and I wanted to ensure the test was fair.

Answer (score 0):

This will find all the words you want /^[a-z]+\s|\s[a-z]+$|\s[a-z]+\s/g so you could use match.

`this.match(/^[a-z]+\s|\s[a-z]+$|\s[a-z]+\s/g).join(" ");` should return the list of valid words.

Note that this took some time as a JSFiddle so it maybe more efficient to split and iterate your list.

Comment: Why not use `\b` after the word as well? And why repeat everything?